# How to GET a Story Point using the jira api

Tags: java, rest, jira

I am sending a request using the JIRA REST API to get a list of closed tasks in a certain date range. However, I set and specified the story point in the task settings. But I did not find them in the response after the get request.
I can't post an example answer because it's too big.

How do I correct a query to get a story point?

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql=project = AUTHPROJECT AND statusCategory = 3 AND status CHANGED AFTER 2024-01-22 BEFORE 2024-01-26
```